# multi filter for controller in ci 4

Tags: php, filter

I create 3 filter for logging data in ci 4.
I have controller like this:

```
$routes->post("data/storeData", "Data::storeData", ['filter' => ['authData', 'logData']]);
```

and i have add this line in Filter.php

```
public $filters = [
    'authData' => [AuthData::class],
    'logData' => [LogData::class],
];
    public array $globals = [
        'before' => [
            // 'honeypot',
            // 'csrf',
            // 'invalidchars',
            'log',
        ],
        'after' => [
            'toolbar',
            'log',
            // 'honeypot',
            // 'secureheaders',
        ],
    ];
```

i want filter "log" implement for another controller, except router for "data/*". but why route "data/*" still impact for filter "log". can anyone help me? thanks and sorry for my english maybe not good